# Office Word "Concise Language" Recommendation

Tags: british-english

Microsoft Office now recommends changing phrases such as:

"will host all of the"

to

"will host all the"

due to this being more "concise" language. However, to me, their recommendation doesn't sound grammatically correct. Is this recommendation sound?

Comment: If you just turn off the MS Word recommendations your life will be simpler and more rewarding.

Comment: @Robusto, I plan on it. I just wanted to check if it was valid or not.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical.